# Deserialize by automatically splitting for each element of a sublist in C#

Tags: c#, json, class, oop, deserialization

It is possible that an answer to this exist but I don't really know how to explain my problem so I'll do it here.

Let's imagine I am grabbing datas from an api in a JSON format. Let's say it has the following format :

```
    {
        "name": "Animals",
        "className": "Mammals",
        "speciesList": [
            {
                "species": "Panthera leo",
                "subspecies": "leo"
            },
            {
                "species": "Equus quagga",
                "subspecies": "quagga"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And I want to store them in the following class :

```
public class Animal
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string className {get; set;}
   public string species {get; set;}
   public string subspecies {get; set;}
}
```

How can I deserialize it with a class so that it creates me 2 objects, as follows :

```
Animal("Animals", "Mammals", "Panthera leo", "leo")
Animal("Animals", "Mammals", "Equus quagga", "quagga")
```

I know that I can extract all but wanted to know if there was a direct way to create this !
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Unrelated: `class` is a reserved word in C#. You should consider a different PropertyName and map it using [JsonPropertyNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-8.0).

Comment: @Fildor thanks yes I knew it was just because I quickly created this example but ive changed it now

Comment: There are different json libarys available like system.text.json or newtonsoft.json etc. for .net 7. What do you perfer? Or what .net version do you want to use ?

Comment: [This Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OH78No) uses intermediate DTOs, but yields your desired output. Would that meet your requirements?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for your reply yes this seems short so it seems good but you are sure that there was nothing else like using get set or something like that to directly split ? If not I'll keep it thanks for that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you want to place all code inside of one class, you can consider this

```
List<Animal> animals = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animals>(json).SpeciesList;

public class Animals
{
    public List<Animal> SpeciesList { get; init; }

    public Animals(string name, string className, List<Animal> speciesList)
    {
        speciesList.ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.name = name;
            x.className = className;
        });
        SpeciesList = speciesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Serge Your answerr seems like the best for me. By the way I don't really understand here : where are the lines that allow you to grab name and className from the Json ? Because I don't see here where you take them. Thank you in advance !

Comment: @Ces Since my code contains a class constructor  Animals(string name, string className, List<Animal> speciesList)   Json using this constructor to deserialize a json string and inserts name and className  from a json string as the constructor input parameters

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying I didn't know it was working like. that. Then thanks a lot you solved my problem !

Answer (score 1):

With *Newtonsoft.Json* library, first you extract the JSON as `JObject`. And extract the `speciesList` array as `JArray`, so you can iterate each element and convert into `List<Animal>`.

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
List<Animal> animals = (jObj.SelectToken("speciesList") as JArray)
    .Select(x => new Animal
            {
                Name = jObj.Value<string>("name"),
                ClassName = jObj.Value<string>("className"),
                Species = x.Value<string>("species"),
                Subspecies = x.Value<string>("subspecies")
            })
    .ToList();
```

Meanwhile, would suggest that to use Pascal case for the property name.

```cs
public class Animal
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string ClassName {get; set;}
   public string Species {get; set;}
   public string Subspecies {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UsI3i5)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to convert the `JSON` data into a `dynamic` object

```
public class Animal
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public string className {get; set;}
   public string species {get; set;}
   public string subspecies {get; set;}
}

// Deserialize the JSON data into a list of Animal objects
string json = "{ \"name\": \"Animals\", \"className\": \"Mammals\", \"speciesList\": [{\"species\": \"Panthera leo\",\"subspecies\": \"leo\"},{\"species\": \"Equus quagga\",\"subspecies\": \"quagga\"}]}";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
List<Animal> animals = new List<Animal>();
foreach (var species in data.speciesList)
{
    Animal animal = new Animal
    {
        name = data.name,
        className = data.className,
        species = species.species,
        subspecies = species.subspecies
    };
    animals.Add(animal);
}
```